# java selenium find element by xpath with variable

Tags: java, xpath

Can I use variable in xpath? For example :

```
findElement(By.xpath("@class='featured-item'"]"));
```

It was working but now it is not. Because class including variable for every item. For example :

```
 findElement(By.xpath("@class='featured-item 1'"]"));
 findElement(By.xpath("@class='featured-item 2'"]"));
 findElement(By.xpath("@class='featured-item 3'"]"));
 ...
```

When I use @class='featured-item' it is not finding items because class name has a variable. Is there any way like :

```
  @class='featured-item \\d+'
```

Comment: Use `starts-with(@class, 'featured-item ')` maybe?

Comment: ty @LewBloch it is worked

Comment: The reason why it didn't work is because xpath doesn't support combined classes in the notation you used. If you would decide to remove the space between 'featured-item' and the digit, you would be totally fine.